# Sorted large list of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, angularjs

I need to handle a **large** list of objects (in that case, sprites in a game) **in a particular order**, determined by one of their property (in that case, the `zIndex` of the sprite). I acquire the objects one-by-one, in a random order, but not so far from the perfect one.

At the moment, I push naively each object I acquire in an array, and I sort it before the operation (with the [`orderBy`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) filter of AngularJS). But the operation is really slow (50% of the total calculation time). What can I do to speed up the process?

I've try to use a sparse array, whose keys are the `zIndex` of my objects, but for a mysterious reason:

- [`angular.forEach`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach) is really slow on the sparse array,
- the order doesn't seem to be preserved when I iterate over the array with a `for ... in` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `array.sort()`. The closer you get to the native browser JavaScript the quicker you're going to get.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Whao! I didn't expect a such impressive difference between `angular.orderBy` and `Array.sort`! The simpliest solution are always the best one, I suppose… Thank you for your simple-yet-effective answer :) .

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `for ... in` loop. From Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

`Iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order.`

`for ... in` will usually iterate over an array in the order that the array properties were defined, which is why sorting doesn't work. Not sure if it will solve your problem, but doing a `var i = 0, l = items.length; for (; i < l; i++) { // do stuff }` will preserve array order, and most likely be the fastest way as it uses native javascript.

If this is the only issue that you're facing, and using a sparse array works with this, then it should be fine.

Comment: But it implies an iteration over all the keys of a (very) sparse array (since the `zIndex` aren't at all consecutives), which will result in a huge overhead, no? The question is: how can I iterate only over the defined values of the array and preserve the order during the operation?